# How to change alignment of menu in asp.net

Tags: css, navbar

I am new to asp.net. How to align menu and menu items in a linear manner. I didnot find any style in the properties of menu items. Please help me.

In the below image the menu items is not proper. How to set them in a correct format
[image]

```
                                  <asp:Menu ID="minimenu" OnMenuItemClick="mini_MenuItemClick" CssClass="portfolio-item" runat="server" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <Items>
                                        <asp:MenuItem Text="MINI" Value="mini" Selectable="false">
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="ECE/EIE" Value="sdaad" Selectable="false">
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Embedded Systems" Value="embeddedMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="VLSI" Value="vlsiMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="DSP/DIP" Value="dipMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>                                                    
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="EEE" Value="qwerty" Selectable="false">
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Core Embedded" Value="coreEmbeddedMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Mat Lab      " Value="matlabMini"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="CSE & IT" Value="qwerty" Selectable="false">
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Java" Value="javaMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Dot Net" Value="dotnetMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Andriod" Value="andriodMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="MECH" Value="qwerty" Selectable="false">
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Simulation" Value="simulationMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                                <asp:MenuItem Text="Hardware Projects" Value="hardwareMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                            </asp:MenuItem>
                                            <asp:MenuItem Text="Civil" Value="civilMiniMenu"></asp:MenuItem>
                                        </asp:MenuItem>
                                    </Items>
                                </asp:Menu>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to look at what css rules are acting on those elements.  I see that the over arching style for the menu is "portfolio-item".  You are using some third party CSS framework.

Assuming you are familiar with CSS (don't need to be an expert) I would look at the element and see what rules are acting on it..

I like using Chrome's developer tools.  Start by right-clicking on the element and selecting Inspect.  Then on the right/bottom of the screen it should show you all the css rules that are applied to that element and which ones are overriding others.

[image: Image of Chrome's context menu selecting an element on a web page, focusing on the Inspect option.]

[image: Displaying Chrome's CSS Style's in the developer tools.]

Using this, you can figure out what is causing it and the best way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

its pure CSS problem if you check via firebug or developer tools you will find that there is some problem 
like 
display:inlineBlock .
float : left / right 
width : auto

...